# Execute command on each subdirectory in the command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to append a '0' to each file name with a single integer as the file name, ie.

> 1.jpg --> 01.jpg

I used the following command, but it did not do anything.
Can you tell the problem or what else to do?:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec fish -c "cd '{}' ; 
for f in *;
  if [ (string length '$f') -eq '5' ];
    mv '$f' '0$f';
  end;
end; " \;
```

The same command seems t work from the commandline, but not when called via a script.
Same thing when I try to call seq (without explicitly mentioned range) from a script... says "missing operand".

Comment: What is working and what isn't working about that script? Did you try to use echo in your loop to see whenever it is actually accessed? Why are you not just grabbing all the jpgs using the search and do the move directly?

Comment: That's what I did in the end; named the accordingly from the beginning.
However, Am new to fish(even scripting to a point), and trying to learn.

The command works when entered via commandline, but not when called from a script.
Have had it happen in "seq" as well... says missing operand.
Don;t know why.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[0-9].???" -printf "mv \"%p\" \"%h/0%f\"\n"
```

This will find all files in the current directory which consist of a single digit and end with a 3 character extension.  If you want directories instead of files (as in your example), replace `-type f` with `-type d`.  If you need to allow for longer extensions you can adjust the search pattern.  If you need to search recursively, remove the `-maxdepth 1` parameter.  The output of this command will be the commands to run to do the renames.  For example:

```
$ ls
10.png  1.png  2.png  3.png

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[0-9].???" -printf "mv \"%p\" \"%h/0%f\"\n"
mv "./3.png" "./03.png"
mv "./2.png" "./02.png"
mv "./1.png" "./01.png"
```

If the output looks right you can run it by piping the output of the find command to your shell:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[0-9].???" -printf "mv \"%p\" \"%h/0%f\"\n" | fish

$ ls
01.png  02.png  03.png  10.png
```

Comment: Building command strings from unknown data and piping them to a shell is often a bad idea. For example, your answer will fail if any filename contains a ``"`` or ends with a ``\``.

Answer (score 0):

A fish solution that doesn't involve the `find` command would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish
for f in *.jpg
    if string match -qr '^\d\.' -- $f
        mv $f 0$f
    end
end
for f in **/*.jpg
    set p (string split --right --max=1 / -- $f)
    if string match -qr '^\d\.' -- $p[2]
        mv $f $p[1]/0$p[2]
    end
end
```

You could do this with a single for loop that gets both the jpg files in the current directory as well as all subdirs:

```
for ***.jpg
    do stuff
end
```

However, that complicates the logic inside the for block because the files in the cwd won't have a directory component.